# Trying to get users who signed in more than x times

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have :sign_in_count in the database users table
Now I'd like to use that feature by creating a list of users who signed in more than x times. This is what I put in the Rails console:

```
users = User.where("sign_in_count".to_i >= 3)
```

But it returns all users regardless of count. I'm using the devise gem, and that's what is incrementing the count. I have trackable in the model.

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax is a little off.  Below should work, not tested though.

`users = User.where("sign_in_count >= ?", 3)`